# ReactiveX: Make Observable.Create() be called only once

Tags: c#, database, system.reactive

I'm trying to build a data access layer with ReactiveX (more precisely, Rx.Net) and SQLite.Net.

Part of the job is making an observable that returns the database connection, so that it can be open lazily, only when needed. This is what I came up with so far:

```
var connection = Observable.Create<SQLiteConnection>(observer =>
{
    Debug.WriteLine("CheckInStore: Opening database connection");
    var database = new SQLiteConnection(configuration.ConnectionString.DatabasePath);

    observer.OnNext(database);
    observer.OnCompleted();

    return Disposable.Create(() =>
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("CheckInStore: Closing database connection");
        database.Close();
    });
});


// Further down the line, a query would look like this:
var objects = connection.SelectMany(db => db.Query<>("select * from MyTable"));
```

Unfortunately, every time somebody subscribes to this observable, a new connection is created. And it is also closed once the subscription is disposed.

I tried using `.Replay(1).RefCount()`, but it didn't change anything. I'm not sure to understand that whole `RefCount` thing anyway.

**How can I make this database connection a singleton?**

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this code, which is equivalent, but doesn't open a DB connection:

```
var conn = Observable.Create<int>(o =>
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Opening");
        o.OnNext(1);
        o.OnCompleted(); //This forces closing code to be called. Comment me out.
        return Disposable.Create(() =>
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Closing");
        });
    })
    //.Replay(1)
    //.RefCount() //.Replay(1).RefCount is necessary if you want to cache the result
    ;

var sub1 = conn.SelectMany(i => Observable.Return(i)).Subscribe(i => Debug.WriteLine($"1: {i}"));
var sub2 = conn.SelectMany(i => Observable.Return(i)).Subscribe(i => Debug.WriteLine($"2: {i}"));
sub1.Dispose();
sub2.Dispose();
var sub3 = conn.SelectMany(i => Observable.Return(i)).Subscribe(i => Debug.WriteLine($"3: {i}"));
sub3.Dispose();
```

There's a number of problems here:

1. Your dispose/unsubscription code will get called everytime you either unsubscribe or complete the observable. Since you're calling `OnCompleted`, it's going to be open/closed every time.
2. If you want to re-use the same connection, you need to use `.Replay(1).RefCount()`. `Observable.Create` runs the whole function every time a subscriber connects, there's nothing (except `.Replay(1).Refcount()`) that caches it for you.
3. Even if you add `.Replay(1).Refcount()` and remove `OnCompleted`, you will still get disposal (meaning DB-Closed) behavior if there's no outstanding subscriptions (like after the `sub2.Dispose()` call).
4. If you don't dispose the subscriptions, either through `using(var sub = connection.SelectMany(...))` or explicitly via `sub.Dispose()`, you'll never unsubscribe, since this Observable has no way of terminating. In other words, opposite problem of 3, your `Close` code will never happen.

I hope you get the picture: This is a pretty error-prone way of doing things. I would recommend a simple iterative call, since that tends to work better for DB calls anyway. If you insist on RX, I would look at `Observable.Using` for your DB connection initialization.